# Solr service not responding with PHP

Tags: php, yii, solr

I'm new to solr ...

I installed it by this command `pecl install solr` on OSX .

And put the extension `extension=solr.so` in `php.ini` then restart by `apachectl restart`.

But still this problem shown

> CException
>
> Solr service not responding.

This is the code :

```
public static function SolrQuery($query,$limit=1,$offset=0,$additionalParameters=array())     
{         
 //echo $query;exit;         
 //var_dump($query); exit;         
 return Yii::app()->smsReportAdmin->get($query,$offset,$limit,$additionalParameters);     
}
```

Please help ...

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Solr using curl on the command line so you remove php out the picture completely. Here is a sample tutorial showing how to do that 
http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/

Lastly maybe post your code that you are using to connect to Solr so I can double check it for you.

Comment: i edit the question and added the code @JeremyQuinton

Comment: Have you actually downloaded and run Solr? And not just the PHP module for talking to it (which is what `pecl install solr` installs)? If you have - http://localhost:8983/solr/ should give you an Admin interface to verify that your Solr installation is actually working. Your code doesn't show anything related to the Solr extension either, so it's hard to say what it should be doing.

Comment: Yes i downloaded by 'brew install solr' and i can open and access localhost:8983/solr and see the interface but this warning still shown after and before install and run solr, so is it about maybe any configuration that must be done usually or what ? Thanks @MatsLindh